# I can't seem to get a service to return data to a controller if data is pulled from json file

Tags: angularjs

I'm sure I have just a simple mistake, but I have searched and searched the web for answers and cannot find anything.

What I am trying to accomplish is to have a service or factory that pulls data from a json file so I can use it by several controllers. If I pulled the data inside the controller is works fine. If I have the json data inside the factory or service it works, but if I try to pull the json data from a file and return it I get undefined inside the controller.

Here are three examples, the first two work fine. But the third one does not.

This works:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("listController", ["$scope",  "$http",
    function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.artists = {};
    $http.get('artists.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.artists = data.artists;
    });

}]);
```

And this works:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.factory('musicService', function($http) {
   var factory = {};

    var data = [
        {
            "name": "pete",
            "age": 21
        },
        {
            "name": "John",
            "age": 45
        }
    ];
    factory.getArtists = function() {
        return data;
    }

   return factory;
});

app.controller("listController", ["$scope", "musicService",
    function($scope, musicService) {

    $scope.artists = {};
    $scope.artists = musicService.getArtists();

}]);
```

But this does not work:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.factory('musicService', function($http) {
   var factory = {};

    factory.getArtists = function() {
        $http.get('artists.json').success(function(resource) {
            return resource.artists;
        });
    }

   return factory;
});

app.controller("listController", ["$scope", "musicService",
    function($scope, musicService) {

    $scope.artists = {};
    $scope.artists = musicService.getArtists();
    console.log($scope.artists);  // return undefined

}]);
```

Here is the sample data in the json file:

```
{ "artists": [
    {
        "id": 1, 
        "name": "AC/DC", 
        "genre": "Rock", 
        "rating": 4
    },{
        "id": 2, 
        "name": "Audioslave", 
        "genre": "Rock", 
        "rating": 3
    },{
        "id": 3, 
        "name": "Beetles", 
        "genre": "Rock", 
        "rating": 2
    },{
        "id": 4, 
        "name": "Depeche Mode", 
        "genre": "Alternative", 
        "rating": 1
    }
]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`factory.getArtists()` is returning a promise, not the actual data. Therefore in your controller, you need use `then()` to get the data and set your scope variable.

Also you need to return this promise from the service method - you are not currently returning anything.

Lastly `success()` is deprecated (see [offical docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice)) - you should use `.then()` inside your service method too, especially as `success()` passes along the original promise from the `$http.get()` call, not what is returned by the `success` callback.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.factory('musicService', function($http) {
   var factory = {};

    factory.getArtists = function() {
        // 1. return the http promise
        return $http.get('artists.json').then(function(resource) {
            return resource.artists;
        });
    }

   return factory;
});

app.controller("listController", ["$scope", "musicService",
    function($scope, musicService) {

    $scope.artists = {};
    // 2. get the http promise and use then() to access the returned value
    musicService.getArtists().then(function(artists) {
        $scope.artists = artists;
        console.log($scope.artists);  // return undefined
    });

}]);
```

Comment: The `.success` method in the factory **ignores** return values. Use `.then` instead.

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot a return her :

var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

```
factory.getArtists = function() {
    //// return her
    return $http.get('artists.json').success(function(resource) {
        return resource.artists;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a promise so it sets $scope.artists after it returns. Until that return occurs $scope.artists is undefined.

The following should work:

```
app.controller("listController", ["$scope", "musicService",
    function($scope, musicService) {    
    $scope.artists = {};
    musicService.getArtists().then(function(data) {
        $scope.artists = data.data.artists;
        console.log($scope.artists); 
    });

}]);
```

Working **[`Application`](http://plnkr.co/edit/bPS4BC1MkphnYJpVfbXB?p=preview)**